# How to list local video files using ionic 2(cordova) like gallery or any media player does

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I want to make an app like media player. Want to list all videos available in the phone/sdcard and clicking on it will start playing. Now I am stuck to display list of local video files. I have tried with http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/ and https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html but unable to get list of videos.

So, please help me to get resolution. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you have done so far and if so what issue did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Transfer, TransferObject} from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html',
  providers: [FilePath, Transfer, TransferObject, File]
 
})
export class ContactPage {
 
 results: any;
 storageDirectory: string ='';
 
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private filePath: FilePath, public platform: Platform, private transfer: Transfer, private file: File){
 
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
 
       // code to create a new directory
 
       file.createDir(file.externalDataDirectory, 'newDir', true).then((result)=>{
    console.log("Directory newDir created" + result);
       
    // code to list the files and folder in the directory

       file.listDir(file.externalDataDirectory,'').then((result)=>{
    this.storageDirectory = file.externalDataDirectory;
    console.log("this.storageDirectory containnig "+ this.storageDirectory);
    console.log("listing taking place here" + file.externalDataDirectory);
         this.results=result;
     console.log("showing result content"+result);
   
 // code to print the name of files and folder on console as well as on device screen  
   
 for(let file of result){
    if(file.isDirectory == true){
  console.log("Code if its a folder");
  let name=file.name; 
  console.log("File name"+name);
 }
 else if(file.isFile == true){
  console.log("Code if its a file");
  let name=file.name; 
  console.log("File name "+name);
  let path=this.storageDirectory+name; 
  console.log(path);
    file.getMetadata(function (metadata) {
   let size=metadata.size; 
   console.log("File size"+size);
      })
 }
 }
   
    
/*result will have an array of file objects with 
file details or if its a directory:  */
    });
  });
  
});
 }
 }
```

Please check this my running code, may can help you to get the list of files and folders from the internal storage.

Comment: attach the error screenshot that u are facing with this code and run it over the device.